# How to detect if the page is slow due to 3rd party javascripts?

Tags: javascript

For those of us who run content websites and deal with Ad networks, combating malicious or malfunctioning rogue ads can be frustrating.

I own a site that embeds a lot of Youtube & Dailymotion videos. Once in awhile, a bad Ad will turn up and make the video playback stutter. I always dealt with these on a case-by-case basis. But, is there a way to detect (using javascript) whether or not the page is slow?

In my head, a very crude way is to have a setInterval running at 100ms. And if it detects a big delay in one interval, act accordingly.

Are there other more elegant approaches?

Comment: I just heard today on a podcast, called Techsnap, that an employee of an ad company said, that they deliberately slow down page loads, to get a londer display time... making more money. So yea, ads, especially flash ones, that is why i have complete disabled flash and everything runs fine.

Comment: @ppumkin Wow, this is one of the many reasons why I think there needs to be a revolution with the web Ads landscape. Too many exploitable areas. Recently, I had to deal with a strange rogue Ad that disables page scrolling and right-clicks...

Comment: Yea... flash is the main source of 0day exploits or exploits in unpatched browsers... The problem is there is no replacement for flash sadly :( And adobe is releasing patches at shockingly low rates and threatening white hat researchers with legal action for reverse engineering and providing patches to Adobe for free. That is one plus on Apple, they solved the problems and banned flash... but the minus is they don't want to share. Google and Firefox are the only active guys developing alternatives to Flash... but its taking ages and very buggy.

Comment: Chrome is blocking Flash Ads starting Sept 1st 2015.  https://plus.google.com/+GoogleAds/posts/2PmwKinJ7nj

Comment: Great news... First YouTube, now the Ads... I like Google for this... Everybody else is still pretending there is nothing wrong with Flash though...

Comment: I think Alan Turing asked the same question once...

Answer (score 1):

First approach, if your slowness is on load, create placeholders for the ads and load them very last after everything else.

Second approach, create a Javascript timer or include a timer library to measure the page load time. If it is greater than your acceptable threshold then kill the ad with Javascript or log the slowness to a web service.

Third approach, if the timer does not pick up the slowness because it is incremental then use a setTimeout function that records a timestamp and calls itself every 200ms and compares the new timestamp each call to the older timestamp from the previous call.

If a setTimeout call set to run at 200ms takes 500ms to finally run then you've got substantial delay and should kill the ad with Javascript or log the slowness to a web service.

Each of these methods will need to be tuned to your actual site.

Comment: If the ad is loaded from flash, javascript wont detect the "slowness" because the javascript engine is still running without lag... its other crap they put into flash that slows down the UI to a grinding halt, on another process, inaccessible to javascript. flash needs to die soon, very soon

Comment: The flash ad may not have overwhelming influence on the javascript engine, but if the ad is causing the rest of the web page to chug due to a complete browser slow down javascript timers will show it.

Comment: I would really love to test that... because from my experience OS lag in general didn't affect browser processes (in memory space processes)... because they are prioritised differently. Chrome has some nice performance testing tools though.

Comment: You're right that it may be a long shot. If the lag is all graphical then the javascript will run as desired.

Comment: Heck, you could write a flash performance tester... :) monitor the user computer CPU usage and dump it into a service... wow, an actual real use case for flash in the modern world :)

Comment: You might run into the same problem though. If the slowness is graphical and not specifically a flash engine issue then the flash performance test might perform well even with a bad ad. :(